# how to change React native app SHA1 value?

Tags: react-native, keystore, sha1, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I have a app along with keystore file and sha1 value. But due to some errors I have to rebuild the app to another app. Now my sha1 value has been changed and I want to give the google play update to same app. I have everything from keystore password to keystore alias name. The google play console is giving this error : "Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:". How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The name of your given file must be the same "name" you have in your `package.json`.

Comment: Yes it is same still the problem occurs